# What is the cardinality of the set of real numbers in union with the set containing the empty set.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I'm trying to figure out the cardinality of $|\mathbb{R}\cup \left \{\varnothing\right \}|$. I think it is $\mathfrak{c}$ because clearly the set has at least as many elements as $\mathbb{R}$ however, I'm having trouble finding an injection from the set to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Are you sure that you're interested in that set? Because $S\cup\emptyset=S$ for every set $S$...

Comment: sorry I fixed it

Comment: Not yet: what's your definition of $\mathbb R$? For example, in my definition $1=\{\emptyset\}$ and $1\in\mathbb R$

Comment: @LorenzoCecchi I don't quite agree with your statement. If I were to follow the set-theoretic definition, then I'd say that the $1$ that is in $\Bbb N$ is $\{\emptyset\}$, the $1$ that is in $\Bbb Q$ is $\{(a,b)\in\Bbb N\times (\Bbb N\setminus\{0\})\,:\, a=b\}$ and the $1$ that is in $\Bbb R$ is $\{q\in\Bbb Q\,:\, q<1_{\Bbb Q}\}$. Anyways, whether or not $\{\emptyset\}\in\Bbb R$ (or even if $\emptyset\in\Bbb R$) does not change much.

Comment: @LorenzoCecchi: an interesting comment. If you want to be set-theoretically literal, then you need to appeal to a construction of $\Bbb{R}$ which preserves the property that $1 = \{0\}$ that holds in the usual construction of $\Bbb{N}$. You should read Beneceraf's paper *What numbers could not be* to see that things are not as simple as you think. (@Gae got it right, but only on the assumption that the real numbers are constructed as Dedekind cuts in a particular way.)

Comment: Yes, of course you are right: the purpose of my comment was to enlight the fact that is not obvious that $\{\emptyset\}\notin\mathbb R$, not to make a set-theoretically precise assertion. My fault

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: this is [Hilbert's hotel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_paradox_of_the_Grand_Hotel) with an uncountable set of rooms that you can leave reserved: map $\emptyset$ to $0$ and then shuffle the numbers in the sequence $\langle 0, 1/1, 1/2, 1/3, \ldots\rangle$ along one place.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the fact that $\operatorname{arctan}:\Bbb R \rightarrow (-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ is a bijection and continue it to a bijection $\Bbb R \sqcup * \rightarrow (-\pi/2,\pi/2]$. This yields an injection $\Bbb R \sqcup * \rightarrow \Bbb R$.